# How to animate scroll view from back of another view

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiviewanimation

In my iPhone app, I have two views on a main view controller , one is normal view 'a' with some buttons and other is scrollView 'b'. When I tap on button in view 'a', I want to show scroll view with animations like the scroll view has to come up from the back of view 'a', but it comes up from the front of view 'a'.

I used the following code for animating the scroll view.

```
CGRect Frame = scrollView.frame;
if(Frame.origin.y == 420){
    Frame.origin.y = 298;
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        scrollView.frame = Frame;
    }];
}else{
    Frame.origin.y = 420;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        scrollView.frame = Frame;
    }];
```

How to implement the animation to scroll view to show it from top of view 'a'.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move "b" to the back first:

```
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:scrollview_b];
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for my problem.

Solution :

```
CGRect Frame = scrollView.frame;
    if(Frame.origin.y == 420){
        Frame.origin.y = 298;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            scrollView.frame = Frame;
            [self.view insertSubview:scrollView belowSubview:view_a];
        }];

    }else{
        Frame.origin.y = 420;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            scrollView.frame = Frame;
            [self.view insertSubview:scrollView belowSubview:view_a];
        }];
    }
```